# How do I using linq-only unwrap multi-dimentional array into a one-dimentional?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to rewrite this function without foreach(), using LINQ-only?

```
    IEnumerable<string> Unwrap(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> data)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            result.AddRange(d);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> Unwrap(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> data)
{
    return data.SelectMany(d => d);
}
```